# Plesk 12 Schedule Task, Manually Force Email on Error

Tags: php, exception, cron, plesk, cron-task

I'm trying to figure out how to make sure that I'm sent an email if an error occurs within the script that I'm calling via URL. I thought that by throwing a PHP Exception, the Scheduled Task would consider that a good reason to email me ... but no.

Is there a way to ensure that the Cron notifies me if the script itself throws and exception, or something similar?

```
try {
    $connect = $rets->Login();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    throw new Exception("caught for demonstration");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Operation System exit code which is not equal to 0 is only good reason to understand that something goes wrong :-)

Scheduled task which executes your PHP script is looks like OS command which execute proper PHP binary:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php /here/the/path/to/your/script.php
```

If exit code of this command is not equal to 0 you'll get email message.

Try to replace:

```
throw new Exception("caught for demonstration");
```

with:

```
exit(1);
```